# In Chrome with multiple users open, how can I quit just one of them?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-users

I have multiple users in Chrome open. Each has multiple windows.

To restore a user not currently open, I can just go to users -> [user x] and it restores properly.

However, how can I *quit* Chrome just for that one user (e.g. to save RAM/CPU when I'm done working in that context for the moment, but want to continue working as other open users)?

Comment: How are you quitting? Does it not work just to use the close (x) at the top right? or does that close all users?

Comment: That would close one window for that user. If I did that for all of that user's windows, when I reopen it, it'll think its last state was only the last-closed window, which'd lose multiple windows per user state that I want to preserve. File -> quit closes all users.

Comment: I really don't understand. I only use 1 user, not multiple users. From your question it seems you want to close all of one user's windows and clicking on the x at the top right closes all of the tabs for that user. Your response seems to say that you are closing each tab separately. Please elucidate.

Comment: I'd suggest just trying it. Add a new user. Each user has their own windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently this feature was implemented. Click on the profile name in the right top corner and click `Close all your windows`. Google Chrome version 59. Sweet!

Comment: Note that this menu option only appears if you have more than one window open for that profile. Otherwise it is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (June 2014) there's no way to do this, but it's been requested, and you can star the feature request if you want to add your support for it:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130656